# How do I delete list items with "clear" button? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

So as you can see the "add" button works fine but I can´t make the clear button to work. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out.

```js
function addToList() {

  let x = document.getElementById("add").value
  let y = document.createElement("li")
  y.textContent = x
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(y)

}

function clear() {
  //????
}
```

```html
<div class="thebox">
  <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
  <input type="text" id="add">
  <button id="btn1" onclick="addToList()">add</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="clear()">clear</button>

  <ul id="list"></ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**clear** is java script inbuilt function. This will not work. Change function name.
Your clear function code can be like this.

```
function clearControl() {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML='';
}
```

Comment: Oh! This might just be it. I have tried several things for my clear function but nothing would work.

Comment: @SamiKärnä if this solution works for you then mark it as accepted answer so that this can help other developers.

Comment: I did, thank you. I am new here so I don't know how this works. I tried to vote you up but my reputation is not high enough to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
function clearChildren() {
 let list = document.getElementById("list");

 [...list.children].forEach(c => list.removeChild(c));
}
```

Comment: clear is inbuild function of java script. This will not work. Some other function name will work.

Comment: @AmitVerma you are right. It should be some other name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not keeping the list in JS-memory, so you can just remove the html of the list.

Something among the following could work (can't test it now):

```
function clear() {
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = ''
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct except function name. Clear is inbuild function of java script. Some other function name will work.

Comment: Ah check, I was wondering why it didn't work when I did a quick check during my meeting ;)

Answer (score -1):

Do you want the list to be removed as well? If not, this will work

```
let y = document.createElement("li")
while (y.lastChild) {
   y.removeChild(y.lastChild);
}
```